# I need to make the Semicircle and Profile balls Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

[image]

The semicircle and profile balls in the above has to be responsive. Unable to do so because the width and height of the elements has to be defined in fixed values. Is there a way to make the semicircle and ball with percentage values?

```css
.profile-container {
  background: radial-gradient(66.2% 209.22% at 48.46% 53.89%, #2E2E3C 4.25%, #1A1A24 100%), #000000;
}

.profile-ring {
  width: 24rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 12rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 12rem;
  background: conic-gradient(from 63.3deg at 50% 50%, #F5E91B -142.46deg, rgba(244, 231, 0, 0.02) 26.63deg, #F5E91B 217.54deg, rgba(244, 231, 0, 0.02) 386.63deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.inner-ring {
  width: 23.5rem;
  height: 11.75rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 11.75rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 11.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: .75%;
  background: radial-gradient(66.2% 209.22% at 48.46% 53.89%, #2E2E3C 4.25%, #1A1A24 100%), #000000;
}

.myprofile-ring {
  width: 12rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 6rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 6rem;
  background: conic-gradient(from 63.3deg at 50% 50%, #F5E91B -142.46deg, rgba(244, 231, 0, 0.02) 26.63deg, #F5E91B 217.54deg, rgba(244, 231, 0, 0.02) 386.63deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
}

.inner-ring-2 {
  width: 11.5rem;
  height: 5.75rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 6.75rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 6.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25.65%;
  background: radial-gradient(66.2% 209.22% at 48.46% 53.89%, #2E2E3C 4.25%, #1A1A24 100%), #000000;
}

.inner-ring-2 p {
  color: var(--clr-yellow);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25.65%;
}

.popover-container-1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.popover-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5rem;
  left: 6rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 21rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #3A3A4A;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(41, 41, 53, 0.2), 1px -1px 2px rgba(41, 41, 53, 0.2), -1px -1px 2px rgba(75, 75, 95, 0.9), 1px 1px 3px rgba(41, 41, 53, 0.9), inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(75, 75, 95, 0.3), inset -1px -1px 2px rgba(41, 41, 53, 0.5);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.popover-content img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 3rem;
  max-height: 3rem;
}

.popover-content>a>img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1.5rem;
}

.popover-button-1 {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(53\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 3.5rem;
  left: 0rem;
}

.popover-button-2 {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(54\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-3 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 7rem;
  left: 2.5rem;
}

.popover-button-3 {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(55\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-4 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 9.5rem;
  left: 7rem;
}

.popover-button-4 {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(56\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-5 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 9rem;
  left: 13rem;
}

.popover-button-5 {
  width: 3.75rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(57\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-5:hover .popover-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.notification-bell:hover .notification-popover-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.popover-container-6 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 5rem;
  left: 19rem;
}

.popover-button-6 {
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(58\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.popover-container-7 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 9rem;
  left: 22rem;
}

.popover-button-7 {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../images/MicrosoftTeams-image\ \(59\).png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-start">
        <div class="profile-ring">
          <div class="inner-ring"></div>
          <div class="myprofile-ring"></div>
          <div class="inner-ring-2">
            <p>My Profile</p>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-1">
            <button class="popover-button-1"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-2">
            <button class="popover-button-2"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-3">
            <button class="popover-button-3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-4">
            <button class="popover-button-4"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-5">
            <button class="popover-button-5"></button>
            <div class="popover-content">
              <img src="../images/contact-online.png" alt="Image">
              <p class="m-0">Harshini Kumar <br><span>Manager</span><br><span>5 issues</span></p>
              <a href=""><img src="../images/call.png" alt=""><span><a href=""><img src="../images/message.png" alt=""></a></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-6">
            <button class="popover-button-6"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="popover-container-7">
            <button class="popover-button-7"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- Notification Container Start -->
        <div class="notification-bell" current-count="2">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-bell "></i>
          <div class="notification-popover-content pt-3 px-3">
            <ul>
              <li><img src="../images/support.png" alt="Image">
                <p class="m-0 ps-2">You have been requested for support by Harshini</p>
              </li>
              <li class="p-0"><img src="../images/support.png" alt="Image">
                <p class="m-0 ps-2">You have been requested for support by Harshini</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Notification Container End -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Profile Container End -->
```

Comment: Use percentage values for dimensions and use rotation to get the images in the right places.